# How to pass state information to the GetAsync completion handler?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, facebook-c#-sdk

Given the following simple code, how can I pass a state object along so that my GetCompleted handler has access to the state I need?  In this case I need the name of the friendlist in the GetCompleted handler, but I see no way to pass it.

Thanks!

```
fbSync.GetCompleted += new EventHandler<FacebookApiEventArgs>(GetFriendListMembersCallback);
fbSync.GetAsync("/" + list.Id + "/members");

[...]

void GetFriendListMembersCallback(object sender, FacebookApiEventArgs e)
{
    /* Here I also need my 'list' variable from the invoking scope, but how do I get it here? */
    dynamic membersDataDynamic = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
    dynamic memberListDynamic = membersDataDynamic.data;
    [...]
}
```

Comment: BTW, I know that the FacebookApiEventArgs has a "userState" parameter, but I'm not clear how or where I provide a state object during or prior to the GetAsync call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State is also refered to as user token.

```
fb.GetAsync(path, parameters, state)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I found the same thing (eventually).  Might be worth considering renaming this.

Comment: we opted to make it similar to WebClient, in WebClient they use userToken instead of state.